# Calling function with spread arguments of type `Parameters<Key>` doesn't type check

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that allows you to dynamically call a member on a class instance. I've made use of `keyof` and the `Parameters` utility type, but I'm getting an error when trying to spread the arguments array into the function call.

What can I do to make this pass the type checker? It *runs* just fine!

```
class C {
    f(a: string, b: number) {
        console.log(`In f("${a}", ${b})`)
    }

    g() {
        console.log("In g()");
    }
}

function callOnC<T extends keyof C>(methodName: T, ...args: Parameters<C[T]>): void {
    const c = new C();
    
    c[methodName](...args);
                  ^^^^^^^  A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter
}

callOnC('f', "", 0)

callOnC('g')
```

Edit: Typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1XQGYAowC5oQBcAnASwDsBzAGmgCM8yBXAW1oFMiBKRFNP4APZkIAkGwB0IARUwADAJJkMmAEQASBGAC+KmhtpbOszr1Rakp6DO7I+-ISLGTpqxVcycVnANyXz5pHRGMmACEiFoYDAQEAB5MlgAHgAVaDYADwI2MgATGABrNgBPAXQ4AD5MZjYCAAsBHIA5MGq8ZJpxTrAiCgg8AAVulpqOCETYAG1kgF1yzjwANwESHJ57YQJI6ABeaDI2AHc4D18+S2AJ6rqG5urpzE7xbt6fJAComPjYTABydB+aCpdNAAAwmJAfOIJX4UH6cIA

Comment: Conditional generic types like `Parameters<C[T]>` are essentially opaque to the compiler so it can't really follow your logic.  If you want to get this to type check, you will need to refactor as per [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), such as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WY3j3N) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so, I could write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: Conditional generic types like `Parameters<C[T]>` are essentially opaque to the compiler so it can't really follow your logic.  If you want to get this to type check, you will need to refactor as per [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), such as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WY3j3N) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so, I could write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)